# Trying to combine code

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, swing

The first code below works and consists of a add customer GUI.  The code below it I copied from another GUI I created, but was having some issues with.  At line 30 in the first code below I have a "CREATE CUSTOMERS" section in which I would like to add the second code stated below.  First, I'm not sure where I need to add it.  Second, there probably is some code that needs to be added, which I'm not sure what or where.  I have tried for the longets time to combine these two with no luck.  I am really new to Java coding and it has taken me forever to get to this point.

First code that works:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class SwimCalc extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
private JTabbedPane jtabbedPane;
private JPanel Customers;


JTextArea NameTextCustomers, ExistTextCustomers, NameTextContractors, ExistTextContractors;

public SwimCalc(){
setTitle("Volume Calculator");
setSize(300, 200);

JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
topPanel.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );
getContentPane().add( topPanel );

createCustomers();

jtabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
jtabbedPane.addTab("Customers", Customers);
topPanel.add(jtabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
              }

/*        CREATE CUSTOMERS        */

public void createCustomers(){
    Customers = new JPanel();
    Customers.setLayout( null );

    NameTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
    NameTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 10, 350, 150);
    NameTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
    Customers.add(NameTextCustomers);

    JButton Exit = new JButton("Exit");
    Exit.setBounds(30,170,80,20);
    Exit.addActionListener(this);
    Exit.setBackground(Color.white);
    Customers.add(Exit);

    JButton AddCustomers = new JButton("Add Customer");
    AddCustomers.setBounds(130,170,120,20);
    AddCustomers.setBackground(Color.white);
    Customers.add(AddCustomers);

    JButton Refresh = new JButton("Refresh");
    Refresh.setBounds(260,170,80,20);
    Refresh.setBackground(Color.white);
    Customers.add(Refresh);

    ExistTextCustomers = new JTextArea();
    ExistTextCustomers.setBounds(10, 200, 350, 60);
    ExistTextCustomers.setLineWrap(true);
    Customers.add(ExistTextCustomers);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){

                                             }
private void Exit_pressed(){
System.exit(0);
                           }

public static void main(String[] args){
JFrame frame = new SwimCalc();
frame.setSize(380, 350);
frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Now here is the code I would like to add to the above code:

```
addCustomer.setMnemonic('a'); 

addCustomer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{

new Customer("Customer"); 
}
} );
custPanel.add(custArea); 
custPanel.add(addCustomer); 

custPanel.add(custRefButton); 
custPanel.add(custMessage); 
custRefButton.setMnemonic('R'); 

custRefButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
{ 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
{ 
custMessage.setText(""); 
try
{ 
File custOpen = new File("customer.txt"); 
FileReader custAreaIn = new FileReader(custOpen); 
custArea.read(custAreaIn, custOpen.toString()); 
custMessage.setText("The file exists and can be read from."); 
} 
catch (IOException e3){ 
custMessage.setText("The file could not be read. " + e3.getMessage()); 
} 
} 
} ); 
return custPanel; 
} 

class Customer extends JFrame 
{ 
private String[] states = {"AL", "AK", "AZ", "AR", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DE", 
"FL", "GA", "HI", "ID", "IL", "IN", "IA", "KS", "KY", "LA", "ME", 
"MD", "MA", "MI", "MN", "MS", "MO", "MT", "NE", "NV", "NH", "NJ", 
"NM", "NY", "NC", "ND", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
"TN", "TX", "UT", "VT", "VA", "WA", "WV", "WI", "WY"}; 
private JComboBox StateList = new JComboBox(states); 
private JTextField NameText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField AddressText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField CityText = new JTextField(25); 
private JTextField ZipText = new JTextField(9); 
private JTextField PhoneText = new JTextField(10); 
private JTextField PopMessageText = new JTextField(30); 
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; 

private AddCustButtonHandler addCusHandler = new AddCustButtonHandler(); 

public Customer(String who) 
{ 
popUpWindow(who); 
} 
public void popUpWindow(final String who) { 

final JFrame popWindow; 
popWindow = new JFrame(who); 
popWindow.setSize(425, 350); 
popWindow.setLocation(100, 100); 
popWindow.setVisible(true); 
setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

Container c = new Container(); 

popWindow.add(c); 

c.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); 

JPanel one = new JPanel(); 
JPanel two = new JPanel(); 
JPanel three = new JPanel(); 
JPanel four = new JPanel(); 
JPanel five = new JPanel(); 
JPanel six = new JPanel(); 

one.add(new JLabel(who + " Name ")); 
one.add(NameText); 
two.add(new JLabel("Address ")); 
two.add(AddressText); 
three.add(new JLabel("City ")); 
three.add(CityText); 
four.add(new JLabel("State ")); 
StateList.setSelectedIndex(0); 
four.add(StateList); 
four.add(new JLabel("ZIP")); 
four.add(ZipText); 
four.add(new JLabel("Phone")); 
four.add(PhoneText); 
JButton addwho = new JButton("Add " + who); 
addwho.setMnemonic('A'); 
JButton close = new JButton("Close"); 
close.setMnemonic('C'); 
JButton deleteFile = new JButton("Delete File"); 
deleteFile.setMnemonic('D'); 
five.add(addwho); 
five.add(close); 
five.add(deleteFile); 
PopMessageText.setEditable(false); 
PopMessageText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER); 

six.add(PopMessageText); 
c.add(one); 
c.add(two); 
c.add(three); 
c.add(four); 
c.add(five); 
c.add(six); 

deleteFile.setToolTipText("Delete File"); 
addwho.setToolTipText("Add "+ who); 
close.setToolTipText("Close"); 

if (who == "Customer") 
addwho.addActionListener(addCusHandler);
close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
NameText.setText(""); 
AddressText.setText(""); 
CityText.setText(""); 
ZipText.setText(""); 
PhoneText.setText(""); 
PopMessageText.setText(""); 
popWindow.dispose(); 
} 
} ); 
deleteFile.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
PopMessageText.setText(""); 
if (who == "Customer") { 
File file = new File("Customer.txt"); 
boolean cusFileDeleted = file.delete(); 
if (cusFileDeleted) { 
PopMessageText 
.setText("Customer file has been deleted"); 
} else { 
PopMessageText 
.setText("There was an erron in deleting file"); 
} 
} 
} 
} ); 
}
class AddCustButtonHandler implements ActionListener { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent addCusHandler) { 
int StateIndex; 
try { 
File file = new File("Customer.txt"); 

boolean success = file.createNewFile(); 

if (success) { 
PopMessageText 
.setText("Customer.txt file created file added"); 
} else if (file.canWrite()) { 
PopMessageText 
.setText("Writing data to Customer.txt, file added"); 
} else { 
PopMessageText.setText("Cannot create file: Customer.txt"); 
} 
try { 
FileWriter fileW = new FileWriter("Customer.txt", true); 
fileW.write(NameText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(AddressText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(CityText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
StateIndex = StateList.getSelectedIndex(); 
fileW.write(states[StateIndex]); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(ZipText.getText()); 
fileW.write(","); 
fileW.write(PhoneText.getText()); 
fileW.write("\r\n"); 
fileW.close(); 
PopMessageText.setText("A new Customer has been added!"); 

FileReader fileR = new FileReader("Customer.txt"); 
BufferedReader buffIn = new BufferedReader(fileR); 

String textData = buffIn.readLine(); 
buffIn.close(); 
} 
catch (IOException e1) { 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e1.getMessage(), "ERROR", 2);
} 
NameText.setText(""); 
AddressText.setText(""); 
CityText.setText(""); 
ZipText.setText(""); 
PhoneText.setText(""); 
} catch (IOException e1) { 
} 

} 
} 
}
```

Comment: Your question boils down to "Please finish my program!" ... maybe you can break down your general query for help into more specific questions? What exactly is your problem? What stops your in combining your code?

Comment: @Arne, I had a seperate GUI that consisted of the second part which worked fine.  I was having other issues within other tabs though, so I made a new GUI that consisted of a customer tab.  I tried to insert all lines of code from the original into the new and it wasn't running because of tons of errors.  I believe it was just a matter of the right placement and renaming issues, but am not for sure.

Comment: If you have tons of errors do it incremental ... start from a running program and then add/edit line by line to get to your target. Just take a part of a program and copy it into another program without much thought is a domed approach.

Answer (score 0):

You really need to learn about [Model View Controller separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller).  The code as its written now horribly mixes in business logic (e.g. an array of US States) with view logic (i.e. all of the UI elements).  Furthermore, the classes are misnamed - a Customer clearly is not a JFrame, so your class should not be called a Customer.  It should be named something like CustomerFrame.

Secondly, your UI itself needs work; do not call "setBounds" like that, instead you should use a LayoutManager which will take care of the sizing and positioning of your elements for you.  I recommend learning [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) but to start with take a look through the [Layout Manager tutorials online](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).

Finally, you really need to start taking ownership of what you are doing and really understand what the code you have copied is doing.  Otherwise you're acting like a [Cargo cult programmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) who is just copying and pasting without really understanding any of the code.

Do those things, try the problem again, and then if you're still stuck post a new question.